# Is there a "rigorous" method for choosing a database?

Tags: database-performance, schema, nosql, rdbms

I'm not experienced with NoSQL, but one person on my team is calling for its use. I believe our data and its usage isn't optimal for a NoSQL implementation.

However, my understanding is based off reading various threads on various websties. I'd like to get some stronger evidence as to who's correct.

My question is therefore, "Is there a technique for estimating the performance and requirements of a certain database, that I could use to confirm or modify my intuitions?".

Is there, for example, a good book for calculating the performance of equivalent MongoDB/MySQL schema?

Is the only really reliable option to build the whole thing and take metrics?

Comment: Rather than building the whole thing, I would suggest that 2 people (or 2 teams) spend a week investigating 2 competing options, build a small prototype and then decide. Don't make performance the deciding factor, but rather ease of coding and maturity of the tools you would end up using, from the developer to the sysadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any kind of rigorous method to choose between a NoSQL or a RDBMS, but I find information in this stackoverflow post pretty interesting:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553860/nosql-use-case-scenarios-or-when-to-use-nosql